# Can I see what happens when I run a DNS query?

Tags: dns

My understanding is that when my computer wants to resolve a host name, it will ask the DHCP-assigned DNS servers first. If those don’t know, it goes and asks the ‘root servers’ who then defer to another server, etc.

Using dig or a similar tool, is it possible to see the string of servers that get asked, in a similar way as traceroute shows how packets travel to a certain destination!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

As others have already answered, most usually a host sends a recursive query to a nominated resolver, often a local server or router, often belonging to an ISP or Google's well-known (distributed) `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.  Typically it will have a couple defined, and if the first doesn't respond, it will move to the next after a timeout.

Name resolvers are free to use whatever algorithm they like, including just ask for `NS` records (for `com.`, `stackexchange.com.` right from the top) then an `A` record.  And also caching, within responded time-to-live parameters.

To find out what a particular name resolver does you'll need to monitor packets or have access to the server.

But you can certainly do it manually if you're trying to follow a chain, such as for debugging broken delegations, missing glue records and so on.

To resolve the `A` record of `www.stackexchange.com`:

Find a root zone server from the list, which every resolver will have installed:
 http://www.internic.net/domain/named.root

We pick the first one, `198.4.10.4`

Ask who to ask:

```
nslookup -norecurse -query=ns www.stackexchange.com 198.41.0.4
```

Root server says "Don't ask me, ask `com` questions at`e.gtld-servers.net`", and helpfully gives the address:

```
Authoritative answers can be found from:
com nameserver = e.gtld-servers.net.
e.gtld-servers.net  internet address = 192.12.94.30
(other answers trimmed)
```

Ask `e.gtld-servers.net` who to ask:

```
nslookup -norecurse -query=ns www.stackexchange.com 192.12.94.30
```

He says "don't ask me, ask `stackexchange.com` questions at `ns-925`", and helpfully gives the address.

```
Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find www.stackexchange.com: No answer
Authoritative answers can be found from:
stackexchange.com   nameserver = ns-925.awsdns-51.net.
ns-925.awsdns-51.net    internet address = 205.251.195.157
...
```

We see that `ns-925` is nameserver for the domain we're after (`stackexchange.com`) so we ask for the `A` record:

```
nslookup -norecurse -query=a www.stackexchange.com 205.251.195.157
```

He says gives a `CNAME` response:

```
www.stackexchange.com   canonical name = stackexchange.com.
```

But as it's a nameserver for that as well, it (helpfully) gave us the the `A` record of the `CNAME` record:

```
Name:   stackexchange.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
```

Comment: Very exhaustive. Thank you so much for writing this down. What I’m trying to do is troubleshoot a connection issue for my DSL. I’m trying to make sure DNS is not the issue, if a delay in the response I get isn’t causing the slow start of connections I’m experiencing despite 20ms ping. I will play around a bit more with dig and see what I find.

Comment: Slow startup of TCP connections has many potential causes, but certainly DNS delays are one of them.  Timing resolution at different DNS resolvers is a good place to start; also `tcpdump -ttt` to see where any pauses are.

Comment: That’s my day gone tomorrow! ;-) Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

A normal DNS client just queries the (DHCP or statically) assigned DNS servers. Only DNS servers usually query root servers, doing a *recursive query*.

You can use a packet capture of your choice and filter for UDP (TCP) source or destination port 53 to see the communication with any DNS server.

Which servers and exact method a DNS client uses is up to the OS or the application and off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for dig +trace. The following command

```
dig +trace networkengineering.stackexchange.com
```

will query the root name servers (NS) for the NS of .com, then the .com NS for the NS of stackexchange and finally will get an answer for networkengineering.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! When computerA resolve domain name . Firstly a recursive dns request will initiate from computerA to local  dns server configured on computerA . If local DNS cache don't have record it will forward request to ISP provided Name server, from name server request is forwarded to root server from root server request will forward to Top level domain servers from top level domain servers request will forward to authoritative dns servers

Flow ...

Local DNS ===> ISP name servers ===> root servers ===> Top level domain servers (TLD)==> authoritative DNS server